# database is unavailable use object construction FIRDatabase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need Help! I am newbie in Swift Developing and I try to connect my app to firebase. But when I try to configure and locate the database I got this error!

"Database is unavailable use object construction FIRDatabase"

Here is my code:

```
let db = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

My PodFile

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

What am I missing here? Need Help. Thanks

Comment: can I see your project file ?

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this in your AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method?

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Did you add the GoogleService-Info.plist to your project?

Are you using the xcworkspace project file instead of the xcodeproj file to open the xcode project?

I do see some references to API naming changes (i.e. FIRDatabase to Database).  I would make sure that's not causing a problem too.

Comment: Yes, I added it but I am using this one.
    FIRApp.configure()
I added GoogleService-Info.plist also. And I open xcworkspace project file.

Comment: In terms of changing FIRDatabase to Database. I tried also to change but it show the error "Use of unresolved identifier DatabaseReference"

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using?  see this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide

Comment: I am using "Using Firebase (4.1.0)".

Comment: Using Firebase (4.1.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.3)
Using FirebaseAuth (4.1.0)
Using FirebaseCore (4.0.5)
Using FirebaseDatabase (4.0.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.1)
Using FirebaseStorage (2.0.1)

Comment: To your comment above about unresolved identifier, did you try Database.database().reference()?

Comment: It seems like your GoogleService-Info.plist is missing.  Have you tried loading it manually?  For example: let db = Firebase(url:"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")

Comment: I tried Database.database().reference() this also but still I got the error

Comment: when I try to use this one let db = Firebase(url:"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")
I got this error:

    Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<Firebase>'

Comment: Ok.  Something isn't quite right here.  Have you tried menu Project -> Clean and Project -> Build?  Kill Xcode and try again?  Is this a clean project built from scratch?  Or did you upgrade the Firebase pod from an older version?

Comment: I will try and inform you later.

Comment: if you can share the project on github, I will take a closer look (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

In New version of Firebase dependancy API are changed little bit.

Don't forget to `import Firebase` & `import FirebaseDatabase`.

Replace with this.

```
let db = Database.database().reference()
```

Comment: I tried this one but it give me an error: "Unresolved identifier Database"

Comment: is that you added `import FirebaseDatabase`?

Comment: Yes I also adde d import FirebaseDatabase. Still not working.

Comment: @Swiftdeveloper Can you provide your code where you getting problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you imported Firebase in your xcode file it will import all the other Firebase derivatives, i.e. you don't need to import both Firebase and FirebaseDatabase.

Make sure you copy pasted the code given to you in firebase setup, and typed "pod init" and "pod install" into your terminal in the root directory of your xcode project.

Finally, make sure that you retype "pod install" after adding the new elements to the pod file. I suspect that this is your issue, as if you don't install the new pods, your xcodeproj will not recognize them